# Second order Euler ODE

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I have problems solving ODE

$$(2x+3)^2y'' +2(2x+3)y'+ y= \ln^2(2x+3)^2+1$$

so I know this is an euler cauchy ODE but the term is $2x+3$!

I tried everything I know to solve it but I have been unable to for at least a day. Can anyone help?

Even if I do take a substitution I get very weird results, and wolframalpha doesn't help because for my input it outputs some imaginary solutions!

Comment: **Hint** Rewrite the equation using $t=\log(2x+3)$. It would work.

Comment: i still cant make it work. would you be so kind to solve it?

Comment: @johndoe I have updated the answer. Sorry about the earlier mistakes. I made an error while calculating $d^2y/dx^2$ Please have a look now. Accept the answer if you are satisfied.

Answer (score 2):

Let us substitute $t = \ln (2x+3)$. This would mean that
$$dx = \frac{e^t}{2}dt; \; \frac{dy}{dx} = 2e^{-t}\frac{dy}{dt}; \; \frac{d^2y}{dx^2} = 4e^{-2t}\left(\frac{d^2y}{dt^2} - \frac{dy}{dt}\right)$$

This gives us
$$4y'' - 4y' + 4y' + y = 4y'' + y = 4t^2 + 1 $$

The general solution of the associated homogenous ODE will be found using the standard substitution of $y = e^{mt}, m \in \mathbb{R}$

We get $$4m^2 + 1 = 0 \implies m = \pm \frac{i}{2} $$
Thus, the general solution of the associated homogeneous ODE is $$y = c_1\cos \frac{t}{2} +c_2 \sin \frac{t}{2}$$

Now, the particular solution will be of the form $$y_p = at^2 + bt +c$$ which on being operated by the ODE gives
$$8a + at^2 + bt + c = 4t^2 + 1$$
Hence, $a = 4, b = 0, c = -31$.
Therefore, your final answer is
$$y = c_1\cos \frac{t}{2} +c_2 \sin \frac{t}{2} +4t^2 -31$$
and on putting the value of $t$, we have
$$y = c_1\cos \frac{\ln (2x+3)}{2} +c_2 \sin \frac{\ln(2x+3)}{2} + 4\ln^2(2x+3) -31$$

PS: Please point out if I made any arithmetic mistakes. The problem can however be solved using this method.

**UPDATE:** Thanks to @Claude Leibovici for pointing out the errors. Hopefully, it is free from errors now.

Comment: There are mistakes. If you plug your solution inf the differential equation you don't get $0$. But the idea of t changing variable was good. Check $y''_x$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Thanks for pointing out that mistake. Was such a rookie mistake tbh. John, please have a look now.

Comment: More than perfect ! $\to +1$ for sure.